# How to add email scheduler in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I want to configure e-mail scheduler in an Asp.net web application and I don't know how to achieve this thing. Does anybody have any idea how I can achieve this? I just want to send emails at specific time.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403354/asp-net-multiple-threads/20403530#20403530

Answer (score 1):

You can use scheduler frameworks such as [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net). You can create Jobs in Quartz.net and creates triggers. Triggers kicks in the job at particular time, day, month, nightly basis etc etc. You will be using Cron scheduler to schedule your jobs (that is triggers).

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to write a good old fashioned console program which sends the emails when it runs. Then you simply use a scheduler to run it on the time(s) you want.

Answer (score 0):

I use next solution.

In your Global.asax add this line to Application_Start method:

```
this.Application["Timer"] = new Timer(new TimerCallback(EMailProcessor.Process), null, 0, 60000);
```

Your EMailProcessor class may look like:

```
public class EMailProcessor
{
    public static void Process(object state)
    {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Hope this is what you need.

UPD: This works because the asp.net application are 'real' applications and running even there are no requests to the server.

Comment: Note that in the default configuration, IIS will shut down your ASP.NET process after a period of inactivity (no user requests) which could result in mails being delayed.

Comment: Yes. But default idle timeout is 20 minutes (it will be turned off if you set it to 0). So if your timer's period is less then that value application will never stop.